# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in

Tags: php, mysql

При запуске программа выдает ошибку:

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in...`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register submit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require "scripts/dbconnect.php";
    $first_name = $_REQUEST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_REQUEST["last_name"];
    $test_for_last_id = "select top 1 * from dbo.users order by id desc";
    $resultmq = mysqli_query($link, $test_for_last_id) or die (echo "<div>Ошибка проверки последнего id</div>");
    $last_id = mysqli_fetch_row($resultmq);
    $last_id = $last_id + 1;
    $add_data_in_db = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('".last_id."', '".$first_name."','".$last_name."')";
    mysqli_query($link, $add_data_in_db);
    ?>
    <h1>Добрый день, <?php echo $first_name; echo $last_name; ?></h1>
    <button><a href="afterrg.html">Привет</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас по всей вероятности $first_name или $last_name не определены(там возможно скрытые ошибки), вот и интепретатор ругается.

Comment: `in` где, в какой строке ? нужно писать в какой строке ошибка. пока что у Вас 2 ошибки(см. ответ)

Answer (score 1):

1) В [die()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.die.php) не нужно использовать `echo`:

```
$resultmq = mysqli_query($link, $test_for_last_id) or 
  die ("<div>Ошибка проверки последнего id</div>");
// в скобках не нужно использовать echo
```

2) Ошибка в запросе:

```
$add_data_in_db = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES 
   ('".$last_id."', '".$first_name."','".$last_name."')";
// last_id это параметр и должен быть $last_id
```